# Sum of vector spaces a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a simple question I can't see why union of vector spaces is not always a vector space?
I'd like to see a proof for this.
I have an example that $ U = \{(\lambda,0)  |\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $ V = \{(0,\lambda)  |\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$

${U \cup V}$is not a vector space.

I can't see why union is $$U \cup V=\{(λ,\lambda)|λ \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ not a vector space. It spans entire $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: $$U \cup V \neq \{(λ,\lambda)|λ \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: What is your question, again?

Comment: My question is how $U \cup V$ is not a vector space

Comment: Sum of $U$ and $V$ is not $U \cup V$.

Comment: In general, if $v\in V$ and $w\in W$ then $v+w\notin V\cup W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ U \cup V=\{(λ,\lambda)|λ \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is not true ! Example :

$(1,1) \in \{(λ,\lambda)|λ \in \mathbb{R}\}$,

but $(1,1) \notin U$ and $(1,1) \notin V.$

Comment: $U_m = \{(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_m,0,..,0)|\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
$V_m = \{(0,..,0,\lambda_{m+1},..,\lambda_n)|\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $0<m<n$ Where $U_m \cup V_m$ is a vector space.I can't get intuition about what's the difference between example in question and this one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the comments already give some hints.

Geometrically, $U$ is the x-axis and $V$ is the y-axis.
If you take the union $U\cup V$, you just get the union of the axes.
But this is not a vector space as it is not closed under addition.
For instance, in $\Bbb R^2$, you have
$$(a,0) + (0,b) = (a,b).$$
But these vectors don't belong to the union. These vectors lie in the plane $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: $Um={(λ1,..,λm,0,..,0)|λi∈R}⊂Rn$ $Vm={(0,..,0,λm+1,..,λn)|λi∈R}⊂Rn$, where $0<m<n$ Where $Um∪Vm $is a vector space.I can't get intuition about what's the difference between example in question and this one.